# how to calculate inverse square root of a square matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, inverse

Can anyone please confirm if this is the right way to calculate the inverse square root of a Degree matrix for Spectral clustering

Given an adjacency square matrix A, adjacency matrix

D is the degree matrix, L the laplacian matrix

`D = np.diag(1/np.sqrt(np.sum(A, axis=1)))`

`L = D @ A @ D`

or should I use

`D = A**-.5`

I am seeing inf values in the resulting matrix with both methods.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked for me.. avoiding any divide by zero situations.

```
D = np.diag(1. / np.sqrt(sum(A, 1)))
```